# Except spin, what quantities could be the sources of a torsion field?

Tags: general-relativity

It is well-known that in the Einstein–Cartan field theory, the torsion source is the spin tensor. One may ask, in general, what quantities could be the sources of a torsion field in a general relativistic theory? or, Can any quantity (such as charge, mass, etc.) be the torsion source in a relativistic theory? Sorry if the question doesn't make sense somehow.